# How to leave value unchanged if left empty in form Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, sql-update

I have an updateform with an file input for adding a picture. What i'm trying to achieve is when I leave that field empty, the file will not be changed. So the photo I've uploaded earlier will stay in there.

My forminput is called: `<td><?= form_upload('aanbiedingfoto');?></td>`

And my database field is called `fotonaam`.

I tried something like this, but it did not work:
`if($_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name'] != '') { $data['fotonaam'] = $_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name']; }`

What am I doing wrong?

My controller:

```
function editaanbieding()
{
    $data = array(
        'Aanbieding' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam'),
        'Tekst' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving'),
        'Prijs' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs'),
        'Conditie' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie')
    );
    if($_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name'] != '') { $data['fotonaam'] = $_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name']; }
    print_r($_FILES);
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '';
    $config['max_height']  = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post('aanbiedingfoto');

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('aanbiedingfoto'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }else{
     $image_data = $this->upload->data();
    }
    $this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data);
    redirect('members/aanbiedingen');
}
```

My model:

```
function edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data)
{
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$id2 = $this->input->post('fotoid');
$id3 = $this->input->post('aanbiedingid');
/*
echo 'bedrijfaanbiedingid ', $id, '<br/>';
echo 'fotoid ', $id2, '<br/>';
echo 'aanbiedingid ', $id3, '<br/>';
die;
*/
$this->db->where('idaanbiedingen', $id3);
$this->db->update('Aanbiedingen', $data);
$this->db->where('idfotoaanbiedingen', $id2);
    $insertfoto = array(
        'fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']
    );
$this->db->update('fotoaanbiedingen', $insertfoto);
$this->db->where('idbedrijfaanbiedingen', $id);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some more code so I could get a full or better view of what you're trying to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: Added my controller and model :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema, Take a look at `$this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data);`, If you don't upload any file, `$image_data` would be `NULL`, how did you handle this? does it work without any error?

Comment: I did the same for my company table and it worked there. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: But that's the problem. when I do not upload a photo I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't upload any file, `$image_data` would be `NULL`.

While there are better solutions, you can fix this as simple as:
Find this section in your model and change it as below:

```
if (isset($image_data)) {
    $insertfoto = array(
        'fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']
    );
    $this->db->where(...); // Fill the blank with correct arguments
    $this->db->update('fotoaanbiedingen', $insertfoto);
}
```

---

### Side note:

This is completely optional. To increase the performance and get rid of probable errors, I suggest the following:

- Avoid of loading libraries or calling methods when not needed.
- Set default value for function arguments.

#### Just as a Demo:

*The Controller:*

```
...
if (! empty($_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name'])) {
    $data['fotonaam']        = $_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name'];
    $config['upload_path']   = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '1000';
    $config['max_width']     = '';
    $config['max_height']    = '';
    $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name']     = $this->input->post('aanbiedingfoto');

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('aanbiedingfoto')) {
        $this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data, $this->upload->data());
    } else {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        // If you want to update the table while the uploading failed
        $this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data);
    }
}
...
```

*The Model:*

```
function edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data = NULL)
{
    ...
    if (isset($image_data)) {
        $insertfoto = array(
            'fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']
        );
        $this->db->where(...); // Fill the blank with correct arguments
        $this->db->update('fotoaanbiedingen', $insertfoto);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. that looks really simple :D

Comment: What's the better solution? I don't need that now, but it's nice to know.

Comment: It is better to handle this in `Controller`. for example, why `upload` library should be loaded or `do_upload()` method should be called while there's no file to be uploaded?

Comment: Ah yes. Maybe I'll do that later. but for now it works fine :D thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll rewrite codes, and will update my answer to illustrate one of the `better` ways ;)

Comment: @KeesSonnema Sorry for the delay, the electricity went off. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This does not really work. I tried it but nothing is updating. what could be the problem?

Comment: @KeesSonnema I forgot the `where()` method. I really don't understand which one of these two is necessary to update `fotoaanbiedingen` table: `$this->db->where('idfotoaanbiedingen', $id2);` or `$this->db->where('idbedrijfaanbiedingen', $id);`. replace that over the `update()` method.

Comment: fotoaanbiedingen belongs to idfotoaanbiedingen. idbedrijfaanbiedingen is just the 'main' id for the table where the id's are stored in. as a join, so I can acces all those tables at once.

Comment: I do not have full vision of your database structure, so all the things I could suggest is write `where()` method before `update()` or make an ASSOC array of `WHERE` clause and pass it directly into the `update()` function as: `$this->db->update('fotoaanbiedingen', $insertfoto, $where);`

Answer (score 1):

put your upload code inside the if statement:

```
    <?php
    if($_FILES['aanbiedingfoto']['name'] != ''){
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('aanbiedingfoto')){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }else{
         $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        }
        $this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data, true);
    }else{
        $this->aanbieding_model->edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data, false);
    }
    ?>
```

This is the edit function

```
    <?php
    function edit_aanbieding($data, $image_data, $uploaded = false){       
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $id2 = $this->input->post('fotoid');
        $id3 = $this->input->post('aanbiedingid');
        /*
        echo 'bedrijfaanbiedingid ', $id, '<br/>';
        echo 'fotoid ', $id2, '<br/>';
        echo 'aanbiedingid ', $id3, '<br/>';
        die;
        */
        $this->db->where('idaanbiedingen', $id3);
        $this->db->update('Aanbiedingen', $data);
        $this->db->where('idfotoaanbiedingen', $id2);
        if($uploaded){      //update photo code
            $insertfoto = array('fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']);
            $this->db->where('idbedrijfaanbiedingen', $id);
            $this->db->update('fotoaanbiedingen', $insertfoto);
        }
    }
?>
```